# How to use JXDatePicker?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingx

I want a datepicker in my jframe. I am using JXDatePicker from SwingX, but I have trouble to find out how it works, the datepicker doesnt show.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();

jLabel2.setText(picker.getDate().toString());
    }
```

what I would like is for the picker to show when on actionperformed of a button and then write the seledted date in a jlabel. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JXDatePicker](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.html) is designed as a component that combines a button, an editable field and a JXMonthView component. The user can select a date from the calendar component, which appears when the button is pressed.

So, don't forget to add your picker to the container, ie:

```
panel.add(picker);
```

Here is an [example](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html).

Comment: can we make the editable field as non-editable by the user i.e. only a button click allow user to add entry in field.

Comment: @AnchitMittal `datePicker.getEditor().setEditable(false);` should do the trick.